# Difference between "could come" and "could've come"

Tags: modal-verbs, comparison, modality, wish

E.g

> "i wish i **could come** to the party"
>   "I wish i **could have come** to the party"

What is the difference between these two sentences? I heard a girl talking to other girl "wish you could come" but what she was talking about some party that was in the past, so my question is, shouldnt she have said, wish you could've come to the party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I wish i **could** come to the party". (They are having it tomorrow at 9 pm)

Since **party** is a specific event, this sentence relates either to the present or to the future.

So, since the party was in the past, that girl made a little mistake, or you might've missed her adding the word **have**.

When we want to express past possibility (the party is already over) the correct form is **could have**:

> "I wish I **could have** come to the party"

We use **could** for past *abilities*, not possibilities:

> I wish I **could** play piano when I was 7. (this use of "could" relates to my *ability* to play piano)

Comment: No, see that's what i was confused about. As in i know what would've , could've means. Here the girls was referring to a party that was in the past.

Comment: @ArdisEll - I wrote that "the girl has either made a mistake, or you failed to hear the **ve** after **could**". You are right: the proper form is **could have**, since the party was in the past (and it's a one-off event).

Comment: @ArdisEll - you're welcome! It's usually best to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer: others may add some detail. (But this particular case is simple)

Comment: Oh okay , thankyou i'll keep this in mind for my future posts :)